# Example of Director, Stage, Group, Actor, Box2D and GestureDector LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx

Im curious to know, cant seem to find on Google or Wiki and solid examples so my quest is to drum up a decent example..using Director, Stage, Group, Actor, Box2D and GestureDector in LibGdx.  (Using Textures, Images, TextureRegions etc)

Would any genius out there have any reference material - example source code so I can learn.

I've looked at dozens of sites, wiki, blogs etc and need some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/codejie - this was down and finally found it online again....

Comment: I'm curios, could you point me to where this link shows what you are asking for?

Comment: It shows how to add Box2d bodies as Actors on a Stage with Groups with TextureRegions and Textures, just GestureDector to add! 

svn checkout http://codejie.googlecode.com/svn/java/gdx/DemoDraft

and [link](http://code.google.com/p/codejie/source/browse/?r=9#svn%2Fjava%2Fgdx%2FDemoDraft-Android)

Comment: thanks, scanned through some files earlier, but was easier being pointed to the exact project.

Comment: The answer link, There's nothing there

Answer (score 1):

I have an example of Scene2D elements with Box2d here:

http://www.netthreads.co.uk/2012/04/23/libgdx-box2d-scene2d-bumpers-demo/