# libGdx How to use images or actor as body

Tags: libgdx, actor, tile

I gone through the libGdx wiki/tutorial but I didn't find example to use an image or an actor as a physics body.
In my game I am adding an actor to the stage.
But I want to add this actor or sprite image as physics body.

I have to drag this actor and even want to detect collision with other bodies.

please give me reference if you have.

Thanks

Comment: @VikalpJain That's just plain wrong. scene2d.ui is for UI only. scene2d is a 2d scenegraph which can also be used with physics entities using box2d and has been done many times before.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit tricky. You don't use an image or an Actor as a physics body.

You will need to implement something like a new "PhysicsActor" which extends Actor. This Physics actor will have a body as a property and will be the bridge between your libgdx scene and the box2d world.

The Actor will update it's position based on the body's position (be careful with the meter to pixel conversion). The Actor will receive the input like a click on it and needs to create a (Mouse-)Joint for the Body to be dragged and follow the mouse.

How you handle the rendering of images attached to the body is also custom. You might give each PhysicsEntity manually a Sprite which will be rendered by the draw-call. Or you will use an editor (RUBE for example, there is also a rube-loader in the Contributions-section of the libgdx forum) which will let you attach images to the bodies and you will read those from the editor.

You might also check this link http://www.netthreads.co.uk/2012/04/23/libgdx-box2d-scene2d-bumpers-demo/ I guess it's exactly what you need, but it seems to be implemented a little bit different. He used some kind of Layer architecture to bridge the libgdx scene and the box2d world.

Comment: I am thinking about combining box2d and scene2d in my next game (if i ever finish this one :P). In my current game i am using worldunits instead of pixels (by using cameras vewport). 1 worldunit would fit 1 meter of box2d. Do i stil have to transform from meters to pixels or can i use this meters to render everything?

Comment: @Springrbua In this case there is no need for conversions, but I would not advise you to go with a 1:1 ratio. From the box2d FAQ: "You should try to get your moving objects in the range 0.1 - 10 meters". Having a 1:1 ratio would allow your objects to be only 10x10 pixels to keep precise results.

Comment: i think you missunderstood... I am using worldunits, which size depends on screen resolution. I say on EVERY screen there have to be 50 tiles x and 32 tiles y. If the screen has a 500 * 320 resolution every tile is 10px. Is screen is 1000 * 640 every tile is 20 px... So 1 meter should be 1 worldunit, which is 10 px on 500*320 resolution and 20 px on 1000 * 640 resolution.

Answer (score 1):

[there is already a question like this on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112868/example-of-director-stage-group-actor-box2d-and-gesturedector-libgdx)

Apart form it [box2d and scene2d](http://www.netthreads.co.uk/2012/03/01/libgdx-scene2d-with-box2d/)