# Stage and Box2d cameras are not aligned

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

In my first game I used Scened2d + Box2d rendering my bodies independently without extending `Actor`. It works, but it is messy and not recommended.

Now in my second game, I would like to do it properly and create a bridge between Scened2d and Box2d by using a physics stage `Stage`.

I found this code http://pastebin.com/rNpxvT80 what does pretty much what I need. However, the stage and box2d cameras are not aligned even if used **`mDebugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined)`** in the `Draw()` method of my `Stage` class called `GameStage`.

I have taken a look on this, but I had no luck [libGdx How to use images or actor as body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306358/libgdx-how-to-use-images-or-actor-as-body).
I know it may be something simple, but is wrecking my head...

Here is the result:

[image]

Here is the full "working" source code:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;

public class Box2D_Platformer extends Game {

    public World mBoxWorld;
    public Box2DDebugRenderer mDebugRenderer;

    public OrthographicCamera mCam;
    public AssetManager mManager;

    public sprite_actor mBall;

    public GameStage stage;
    public SpriteBatch batch;

    public static final float PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT = 32f;
    static final float one_over_60 = 1f / 60f;

    @Override
    public void create() {

            init();
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
            stage = new GameStage();

            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
            stage.setupStage(mCam, mBoxWorld, mDebugRenderer);

            stage.addActor(mBall);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
            stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 30f));

            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            render_physics();
            stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
            stage.dispose();
            mManager.dispose();
    }

    private void init() {
            mManager = new AssetManager();
            mCam = new OrthographicCamera(1024, 768);
            mCam.update();
            init_physics();
            init_ball();
    }

    private void init_physics() {
            mBoxWorld = new World(new Vector2(0, -200), true);
            mDebugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

            create_static_object_floor();
    }

    private void init_ball() {

            TextureAtlas atlasSprites;
            mManager.load("data/atlas.txt",TextureAtlas.class);
            mManager.finishLoading();
            atlasSprites = mManager.get("data/atlas.txt");
            TextureRegion t =  atlasSprites.findRegion("bar");

            //
            mBall = new sprite_actor(mBoxWorld, new Sprite(t));
    }

    private Body create_dynamic_object_ball() {
            BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
            bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
            bodyDef.position.set(100 / PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,5000 / PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT );

            Body body = mBoxWorld.createBody(bodyDef);

            // Create a circle shape and set its radius to 6
            CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
            circle.setRadius(1f*PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);

            // Create a fixture definition to apply our shape to
            FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
            fixtureDef.shape = circle;
            fixtureDef.density = 0.5f;
            fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
            fixtureDef.restitution = 1f; // Make it bounce a little bit

            // Create our fixture and attach it to the body
            Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

            circle.dispose();

            return body;
    }

    private Body create_static_object_floor() {
            BodyDef groundBodyDef = new BodyDef();
            groundBodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(0, 10));
            Body groundBody = mBoxWorld.createBody(groundBodyDef);
            PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();
            groundBox.setAsBox(mCam.viewportWidth, 10.0f);
            groundBody.createFixture(groundBox, 0.0f);
            groundBox.dispose();

            return groundBody;
    }

    private void render_physics() {mDebugRenderer.render(mBoxWorld, mCam.combined);}

    private float to_world_x(float size) {return size /PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;}

    private float to_world_y(float size) {return size /PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;}

    private class sprite_actor extends Actor {

            private Body mBody = null;
            private Sprite mSprite;

            public sprite_actor(World world, Sprite sprite) {
                    this.mSprite = sprite;

                    create_body();
            }

            @Override
            public void act(float delta) {
                    super.act(delta);
            }

            @Override
            public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    setRotation(MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * mBody.getAngle());
                    setPosition(to_world_x(mBody.getPosition().x),to_world_y(mBody.getPosition().y));

                    batch.draw(mSprite, getX(), getY());

                    System.out.println("("+to_world_x(mBody.getPosition().x)+","+to_world_y(mBody.getPosition().y)+")");
            }



            private void create_body() {
                    mBody = create_dynamic_object_ball();
            }

    }

    private class GameStage extends Stage {
            private World world;
            private OrthographicCamera camera;

            public void setupStage(OrthographicCamera cam, World box_world,Box2DDebugRenderer renderer) {
                    this.world = box_world;
                    this.camera = cam;
            }

            @Override
            public void act(float step) {

                    world.step(one_over_60, 6, 2);
                    super.act(step);
            }

            @Override
            public void draw() {
                    mDebugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
                    super.draw();
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use two different cameras. The physics debugging camera should use viewport size / PIXEL_PER_METER. The Sprite camera has the standard viewport size.

Comment: thanks @noone, and just managed to get it working by setting ``batch.setProjectionMatrix(mCam.combined);`` in the ``Draw`` method of my ``Actor`` class.
Which one would be more recommended, two cameras or the one above?