# Libgdx different input listener for each object

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I am in the middle of trying to create a game and need to have multiple different input listeners (detectors) for each object. I have a class called "Blocker" which is where my "block" shape is created. In my main gamescreen class I am creating an array of 10 Block instances from the Block class since I need 10 "blocks"

I have implimented the GestureDetector interface directly in the Block class.

Here is the Block class:

```
public class Block implements GestureDetector.GestureListener {
    GameScreen gameScreen;
    Controller game;

    public Body block;

    float screenWidth;

    Stack distance;
    Stack time;

    //Calculated speed to be used once block is released
    public float speed;

    //Becomes true when user starts panning
    public boolean isPaning = false;
    public boolean isReleased = false;
    public boolean isActive = false;

    //Tracks user drag location
    public float panLocation;

    //Becomes true when the user release block
    public boolean released = false;

    public Block(GameScreen gameScreen, Controller game){
        this.gameScreen = gameScreen;
        this.game = game;

        distance = new Stack();
        time = new Stack();

        screenWidth = gameScreen.screenWidth;

        //Creates block that stops balls
        block = createBlock();
        //Sets properties
        setBlockProperties(block);
    }

    public Body createBlock(){
        float tmp = (screenWidth - gameScreen.goalPostThickness);
        float xPos = tmp/gameScreen.PPM;
        Body bBody;
        BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
        def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        def.position.set(xPos, 0);
        def.fixedRotation = true;
        bBody = gameScreen.world.createBody(def);

        return bBody;
    }


     //Sets radius, density, etc.
    public void setBlockProperties(Body body){
        float gbt = screenWidth / 75;  //Goal post thickness

        // Create a circle shape and set its radius to 6
        PolygonShape square = new PolygonShape();
        square.setAsBox(gameScreen.goalPostThickness/gameScreen.PPM, (gameScreen.goalWidth/2)/gameScreen.PPM);

        // Create a fixture definition to apply our shape to
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = square;
        fixtureDef.density = 3.5f;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f; // Make it bounce a little bit

        fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = 0x0004;
        fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = 0x0002;

        // Create our fixture and attach it to the body
        Fixture fixture = block.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        square.dispose();
    }

    //EVERYTHING BELOW IS FOR USER INPUT
     @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                                                                              return false;
                                                                                           }

    @Override
    public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
                                                                      return false;
                                                                                   }

    @Override
    public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
                                                     return false;
                                                                  }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
                                                                             return false;
                                                                                          }

    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        isPaning = true;

        Vector3 input = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double seconds = currentTime / 1000.0;
        //Input is backwards (Y down) to camera so this swaps it
        game.cam.unproject(input);
        float meters = input.y / gameScreen.PPM;
        distance.push(new Double(meters));
        time.push(new Double(seconds));

        setPanLocation(input.y);

        //Incase pan stop is not triggered, speed is still calculated
        if ((input.y / gameScreen.PPM) >= gameScreen.boundaryLocation){
            isPaning = false;
            speed = calculateSpeed(distance, time);
            setCheckRelease(true);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        isPaning = false;

        Vector3 input = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double seconds = currentTime / 1000.0;

        //Input is backwards (Y down) to camera so this swaps it
        game.cam.unproject(input);
        float meters = input.y / gameScreen.PPM;
        distance.push(new Double (meters));
        time.push(new Double (seconds));

        speed = calculateSpeed(distance, time);

        //System.out.println("Calculated speed: " + speed );
        //System.out.println("Stop time: " + meters);
        setCheckRelease(true);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
                                                                     return false;
                                                                                  }

    @Override
    public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void pinchStop() {

    }

    public void setPanLocation(float v){
                                              panLocation = v;
                                                              }

    public float getPanLocation(){
                                        return panLocation;
                                                           }

    public void setCheckRelease(boolean check){
                                                     released = check;
                                                                      }

    public boolean getCheckRelease(){
                                           return released;
                                                           }

    //Calculates speed from the drag time and distance
    public float calculateSpeed(Stack distance, Stack time){
        boolean checkDifference = false;
        int popCount = 0;

        double tmpDis = 0;
        double tmpTime = 0;

        double endDistance = (Double) distance.pop();
        double endTime = (Double) time.pop();

        //pop elements until there can be a calculated difference
        //between start and end time/distance
        while (!checkDifference) {
            tmpDis = (Double) distance.pop();
            tmpTime = (Double) time.pop();

            if (tmpDis != endDistance && tmpTime != endTime){
                checkDifference = true;
            }
            popCount++;
        }
        //System.out.println("Pop count: " + popCount);

        double startDistance = tmpDis;
        double startTime = tmpTime;

        double finalDistance = endDistance - startDistance;
        double finalTime = endTime - startTime;

//        System.out.println("START DISTANCE: " + startDistance);
//        System.out.println("START TIME: " + startTime);
//        System.out.println("END DISTANCE: " + endDistance);
//        System.out.println("END TIME: " + endTime);
//        System.out.println("FINAL DISTANCE: " + finalDistance);
//        System.out.println("FINAL TIME: " + finalTime);


        double speed = (finalDistance/finalTime);
        float tmp = (float) speed;

        //System.out.println("DOUBLE SPEED: " + speed);


        return tmp;

    }
}
```

I am using the inputMultiplexer in my gamescreen class to try and create the multiple input listeners:

```
        multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
            blockObj[i] = new Block(this, game);
            multiplexer.addProcessor(new GestureDetector(blockObj[i]));
        }
```

I am using an isActive variable to set which block is currently being used. However even though this works, as soon as the next block becomes active, it is taking the information from the previous blocks such as drag location.

Comment: Perhaps you can improve a bit your question, imho, by clarifying your request. You have described your problem but it is not clear if you are requesting a (i) from scratch architecture suggestion or (ii)to find out the problem in your code. Usually imho it is better to separate the effective question/request in a clear sentence (that is also a summary), for example: "Do you have an alternative approach to my problem?".. or similar.. "

Answer (score 0):

The reason other blocks are receiving touch events from other blocks etc, is because of how you designed it. Currently, with your design, I can't think of a logical way around this.

However, with a little refactoring, I think you can get just what you want. First, I recommend you look into [scenes](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d). Your `Block` class should extend `Actor`.

By doing this, we are able to use the Block with a stage and do many more complex things with it. You should definitely look at the `hit()` method in actor. You will want to override that method so the Block can work with touch events.

If you look at the "Other listeners" section of that Scenes2d tutorial I linked above, you can see that it supports an `ActorGestureListener`.

This would probably require a lot of refactoring and I can't guarantee it's the best solution because I can't see all your code and I don't know what you're trying to do, but what's wrong with your current set up is that all the blocks receive events when the screen is touched, not just blocks that are actually touched.

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion. I am a little worried about how actors and scene2d will work with what I already have. You mentioned that I wouldn't need a whole lot of refactoring. If I also have non-animated regular shapes from shaperenderer, would I need to also change those to actors? Also will the actor interface work fine with box2d?

Comment: Here is the gamescreen class that impliments all the shaperenderer non animated shapes and the box2d "blocks": https://pastebin.com/ZPtRRARs     Actors do seem like a good fit since it would work well for controlling multiple actors but I am unsure of how I could use a box2d body as an actor.

Comment: @NickHudson here's a link that might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306358/libgdx-how-to-use-images-or-actor-as-body . It doesn't seem like there's a perfect way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Extending the BLOCK class as Actor will allow you to attach listeners in main code. Then, you can use:

```
for(Block block : blockobj)
{
  block.addListener(new InputListener(){  

   //You can add different listeners like ActorGestureListener etc...
   // press Ctrl + O while the cursor is inside this block to override methods.


 });


}
```